# Proof that if $\forall a f(a) = g(a)$ then $f=g$

Tags: functions, polynomials

How do we prove formally that if:
$\forall a f(a) = g(a)$

$=>$
$f=g$

when
$f,g \in \mathbb F[x]$

Comment: Isn't this the definition of $f=g$?

Comment: Tell that to my professors o.O

Comment: Maybe it would be better to put the polynomials tag back. The functions are indeed equal. Not the polynomials in general. So it all depends on what the OP was asked to prove. For instance, $X^p\neq X$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$, although any evaluation yieds the same value over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: The question is not well posed, since $\Bbb F[x]$ does not contain functions. If you want to talk about the associated polynomial functions, you should specify their domain. If you don't do this, one might specialise the $\forall a$ by $a=x\in\Bbb F[x]$, and obtain the result trivially (but this is just cheating, intended to show that talking about functions without a domain makes no sense).

Comment: What domain does $a$ range over? If $a$ ranges over, say, $\mathbb{F}[x]$, then the question is trivial. (plug in $a=x$)

Comment: One might want to recall that $\mathbb F[X]$ denotes the vector space whose elements are the sequences $(a_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ with values in $\mathbb F$ such that $a_n=0$ for every $n$ large enough. For example $X=(0,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ and $X^3=(0,0,0,1,0,\ldots)$ hence $X\ne X^3$ in every $\mathbb F[X]$ although these two polynomials give the same element of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ when *evaluated* at any element $x$ of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ since $x=x^3$ for $x=0$ and for $x=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{F}$.

An element of $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is a **formal** expression. Such a formal expression $f(x)$ defines a **function** from $\mathbb{F}$ to $\mathbb{F}$. This kind of function is called a *polynomial function*. It is common to denote the polynomial $f(x)$ and the associated polynomial function by the same name.

For this problem, that's not a good idea. So for any polynomial $P(x)$, denote its associated polynomial function by $P^\ast(x)$. In that notation, we want to prove that if $f^\ast(a)=g^\ast(a)$ for all $a$ in $\mathbb{F}$, then $f(x)=g(x)$.

We will need to assume that the field $\mathbb{F}$ is **infinite**. For if the field is finite, the result is no longer true.

Suppose $f^\ast(a)=g^\ast(a)$ for all $a$ in the field, but that $f(x)$ is not the same polynomial as $g(x)$. Then the polynomial $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is not the zero polynomial.

Since $f^\ast(a)=g^\ast(a)$ for all $a$ in $\mathbb{F}$, it follows that every $a$ in $\mathbb{F}$ satisfies the equation $h^\ast(a)=0$. If $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite, this is impossible. For a polynomial of degree $n\ge 1$ has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: And that's most likely what the exercise was about, +1.

Comment: (+1) I like this answer, it points out the difference between a polynomial and its associated function clearly.

Comment: Aren't you confusing an infinite field with a field of characteristic 0?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: I don't think so. The result that if two polynomials determine the same function, then they are the same is true for **all** infinite fields. It is true in all fields of characteristic $0$, since they are all infinite. But it is also true for any infinite field of characteristic $p$. The only "bad" fields are the finite fields.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I make the same mistake the statement only works for field of characteristic 0 in one of my comments before (now deleted). As long as the field is infinite, the function does determine the polynomial.

Comment: I got confused.
What exactly is the "function" here and what exactly is the polynomial? Did you give the notation $ P*(x) $ for the function and $ P(x) $ for the polynomial?

Comment: And I do not quite understand the difference between having a finite field and an infinite field in this context... (please excuse my understanding of the answer)

Comment: Let $F$ be the finite field of $3$ elements. Let $f(x)=2x^3-2x$ and let $g(x)=x^3-x$. There are **different** polynomials. But you can check by substitution that both of them produce the identically $0$ function from $F$ to $F$. The same phenomenon can be produced in any finite field. But not in an infinite field, proof given in answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends somewhat on what it means for $f=g$ to hold.  One approach is to consider functions as sets of ordered pairs, if $f(x)=x^2$ then $f=\{(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(-3,9),\ldots\}$.  But not just any set of ordered pairs, we need each element of the domain to appear as the first element of an ordered pair exactly once.

If this is the definition of functions, then we prove this theorem via set inclusion.  For each $a$ in the domain, there is exactly one $f(a)$ such that $(a,f(a))\in f$.   But applying the hypothesis, $(a,(g(a))=(a,f(a))\in g$, so $f\subseteq g$.  Repeating in the other direction $g\subseteq f$ and hence $f=g$.

Comment: "If this is the definition of functions..." as far as I know, *this* is the formal definition of function. Do you know any other?

Comment: I've seen several definitions of functions.  Function as relation (as in my answer).  Function as black box (in which case the problem is moot, since the desired conclusion *is* the definition of equality).  Function as digraph.

Comment: I honestly have no pale idea what black box or digraph can possibly mean in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

By definition two maps: $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon C\to D$ are equal if $A=C$ and $B=D$ and $\forall x\in A=C$ we have $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: Do you intend to imply that the answer to the question is negative, since for $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to D$ one has $f\neq g$ when $B\neq D$ even if $\forall x\in A: f(x)=g(x)$ may hold (the values are in $B\cap D$)?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen by this definition I say yes and the difference appears when we compose $h\circ g$ and $h\circ f$

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen another reason more pertinent suppose we want extend the map $g$ by $g(a)\in D$ and what happen if $f(a)=g(a)\not\in B$?

Comment: Is that "yes, I intend to imply ..."? In that case you might say so more explicitly. I don't have an issue with your definition, but just would like the intention of the answer to be more easily detected.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this will only work in an infinite field. As a counterexample (for a finite field) you can take $\prod\limits_{a\in \mathbb F} (x-a)$, which is $0$ on $\mathbb F$, but its coefficients are different from the zero polynomial.

For an infinite field, you can show that $f = 0$ iff $f(x) = 0 \forall x \in \mathbb F$ (a polynominal has at most $\operatorname{deg} (f) $ zeros), thus $f-g = 0$ holds iff $f(x) = g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb F$.

Answer (score 0):

Using purely set theoretical definitions, recall that a function is a set of ordered pairs, $F$, with the following property: $$\forall x\forall y\forall z(\langle x,y\rangle\in F\land\langle x,z\rangle\in F\rightarrow y=z),$$
that is if $x$ is in the left coordinate of an ordered pair in $F$, then there is only one ordered pair that $x$ is its left coordinate.

This allows us to identify $y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in F$ with $F(x)$.

Now to continue with the argument, recall that $\langle x,f(x)\rangle\in f$ and $\langle x,g(x)\rangle\in g$. By our assumption that $f(x)=g(x)$ we have that $f\ni\langle x,f(x)\rangle=\langle x,g(x)\rangle\in g$, therefore $f\subseteq g$ and $g\subseteq f$, so equality ensues.

Answer (score 0):

While it is trivial that $f,g$ are equal as *functions* iff they agree on all arguments, it is less obvious that it implies equality as polynomials.

If coefficients are assumed to belong to an infinite field $\Bbb{F}$, then it is true that $f=g$ as polynomials iff $f(a)=g(a)$ for all $a \in \Bbb{F}$.

To prove this it suffices to consider polynomial $f-g$ has an infinite number of roots.  Therefore $f-g$ must be the zero polynomial, since otherwise the number of roots is bounded above by the degree of $f-g$.

In finite fields it is possible to give a nonzero polynomial whose roots include all elements of the field, so the above proof fails.